# Angular 8 return focus to trigger element after closing modal

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, focus, accessibility

For screen reader usability I need to return the focus to the element that triggered the modal launch after closing the modal. I have a modal service with

```
showModal(type: string, config: ModalConfiguration) {
    setTimeout(()=> {
        this.store.dispatch(new ModalAction.ShowModal({ modalType: type, modalConfig: config }));
    }, 100);
  }

  hideModal() {
    this.store.dispatch(new ModalAction.HideModal());
  }
```

And the function called on the trigger element is this

```
login() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.modalService.showModal(ModalService.LOGIN_MODAL, { ...new ModalConfiguration(), title: "Sign In" });
    }, 200);
  }
```

I have tried setting activeElement in the modal service but it returns focus to the body. Any help would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 1):

Expose a property in the modal service:

```
returnFocusElementId: string;
```

Set it something like

```
modalService.returnFocusElementId = '#submitButtonId'; // the id of the element which triggers the modal to open
```

Now change the hide modal something like this:

```
hideModal() {
    this.store.dispatch(new ModalAction.HideModal());
    let elementToFocus = document.querySelector(this.returnFocusElementId);
    if (elementToFocus != null) {
        elementToFocus.focus();
    } else if (<HTMLElement>document.activeElement != null) {
        (<HTMLElement>document.activeElement).focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I don't necessarily know the id. It's a large site and I was looking for a universal solution. I'm wondering if I could pass the id into the show modal function. and have it available in the hidemodal. This is a good start!

Comment: Sure. I think you can pass the id of the element calling the `showModal()`, save it in a variable in the service and use it later in the `hideModal()`.

Comment: Working on it. I have a hundred calls for this! Thanks again!